# A subspace of a set of bounded and continuous functions is closed in this set and the ideal of this set

Tags: real-analysis, commutative-algebra, compactness, real-numbers

Question:

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space. For a given $x_0 \in X$, define $C_{x_0}(X,\mathbb{R})$ by $$C_{x_0}(X,\mathbb{R}) = \{f \in C(X, d):f(x_0) = 0\}$$

Note that $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ denotes all bounded and continuous functions from $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and the topology is supnorm

Show that:

(1) $C_{x_0}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $C(X,\mathbb{R})$

(2) $C_{x_0}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is an ideal of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$

Thought:

For first problem, consider a linear function $l(f) = f(x_0)$, then $l$ is continuous

Also, we know that $C_{x_0} = l^{-1}(\{0\})$, which is the preimage of a closed set under a continuous mapping

Therefore, $C_{x_0}$ is closed in $C(X, \mathbb{R})$

Intuitively, I understand why $l$ is continuous, but how to prove it rigorously? For question (2), I know that $C_{x_0}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is actually a subspace of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$, which is a commutative algebra with a
multiplication identity. Then what should I do with this statement?

Comment: For 1, note that for the $l$ you defined, $\left|l(f) - l(g)\right| = \left|f(x_0) - g(x_0)\right| \le \sup_{x \in X} \left|f(x) - g(x)\right|$.

For 2, you need to show that if $f,g \in C_{x_0}$ and $h\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$ then $f+g , (-f)\in C_{x_0}$ and $f\cdot h\in C_{x_0}$. Can you proceed? Edit: you also need to show that the $0$ function belongs to $C_{x_0}$.

Comment: @j3M For 1, could you explain further, why does $|l(f) - l(g)| \leq sup_{x \in X} |f(x)- g(x)|$ implies that $l$ is continuous?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator